# Viideo.JS Thumnails: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, video, undefined, video.js

I am trying to hack the video.js html5 player a bit to display timeline thumbnails during mouse hover (like on yoube). I have came across this plugin here:  https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-thumbnails

It works, but my main problem with this is that my videos are different in length, and are a lot of them on the server (basicaly it is an adult site). 
All the videos thumbnails are generated in a folder, a total 19 of them.

I have modified the original code, so all 19 of thumnails get used in the scene. The site uses smarty.
Went from this:

```
video.thumbnails({
  0: {
    src: 'http://example.com/thumbnail1.png',
    width: '120px'
  },
  5: {
    src: 'http://example.com/thumbnail2.png'
  }
});
```

To this:

```
{php}
global $video, $tmbint;
echo "<script>";
echo "video.thumbnails({";

for($i = 0; $i <= 19; $i++) {

    if($i == 0) { echo "0: { src: '/media/videos/tmb/".$video['VID'].'/'.($i+1).".jpg', style: { width: '120px', left: '-60px' }  }"; }
          else  { echo $i * $tmbint.": { src: '/media/videos/tmb/".$video['VID'].'/'.($i).".jpg', style: { width: '120px', left: '-60px' }  }"; }
    if($i != 19) echo ", \n";
}


echo "});";

echo "</script>";

{/php}
```

I also had to modify the original videojs.thumbnails.js to check the video length and drop in the thumnails equally depending on the length of the video.

Originally it was this:

```
mouseTime = Math.floor((left - progressControl.el().offsetLeft) / progressControl.width() * duration);
      for (time in settings) {
        if (mouseTime > time) {
          active = Math.max(active, time);
        }
      }
      setting = settings[active];
      if (setting.src && img.src != setting.src) {
        img.src = setting.src;
      }
      if (setting.style && img.style != setting.style) {
        extend(img.style, setting.style);
      }

      width = getVisibleWidth(img, setting.width || settings[0].width);
      halfWidth = width / 2;
```

Then I turned it into this:

```
 mouseTime = Math.floor((left - progressControl.el().offsetLeft) / progressControl.width() * duration);

  unit = (progressControl.width()) / 20;
  moffset = left;

  for (time in settings) {
    if (mouseTime > time) {
      active = Math.max(active, time);
    }
  }

  active = Math.floor(moffset / unit) * Math.floor(duration / 20);

  setting = settings[active];
  if (setting.src && img.src != setting.src) {
    img.src = setting.src;
  }
  if (setting.style && img.style != setting.style) {
    extend(img.style, setting.style);
  }

  width = getVisibleWidth(img, setting.width || settings[0].width);
  halfWidth = width / 2
```

However, I get the error in the title. The first 10 seconds are okay, but then it drops the error rapidly, when trying to move on to the second thumbnail and so on. Sorry for the long post, it is my first time here. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like the index of the array you're using [active] might going out of range...

Comment: If I reduce it to 1 it is good, but only shows one thumbnail throughout the whole squence. If I adjust it to 2, then it applies the thumbnail to half of the video and throws in the error  again.

Answer (score 0):

Whooops!  I found out the error. The $tmbint  was zero. I added this line in a seperate PHP file:

```
$tmbint = @floor($video['duration'] / 20);
```

Now it works.